# Playing tenor sax is easy for me. Is a clarinet really that hard?

Tags: saxophone, clarinet, tenor

I have a hard time getting notes out of my Artley clarinet.  The guy who worked on it and inspected it (I bought it from a friend) said it's a good instrument, and he's done great work on my sax so I trust him.

Getting notes out of this thing is tough esp. staying in the low register and not modulating up to the octave+plus+fifth above.  Any tips?

Comment: Reading this question made me think of famous last words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the beginner issues with clarinet is covering the 7 main tone holes cleanly.  If your finger isn't covering it fully, the gap will act like a leaky pad.  I think this is the most likely source of your problem.

It could also just be a leaky pad somewhere.  The side keys (especially the top two) and the G#/A keys are very common culprits.  The tech might not have checked it that thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the instrument is in good repair, and you're covering the holes properly with your fingers, I think you just have to adjust your playing technique down to clarinet size.  Speaking very broadly, you blow a sax harder than a clarinet.

Comment: That's rather broad.  For one thing, "blow harder" is not a term any respectable sax or clarinet teacher would use.

Comment: Yes, it's very broad.  Like I said.  But there's nothing wrong with 'blow harder'.  It was often a useful suggestion in the years I spent teaching wind instruments. Perhaps I wasn't respectable.

Comment: As an exhortation while a student is playing for you, sure.  Here in a forum,  how about  "produce a greater volume of controlled airflow" ?

Comment: Doesn't that translate as 'blow harder'?  :-)

Comment: Well now it's time to go all the way down -- only a blowhard would blow harder than a hard blow would cause.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on just what you're finding difficult with the clarinet.  As Matt P said, you do have to make sure you're covering the holes properly.   In general,  you need a much firmer embouchure for the clarinet than for any sax.  Obviously breath control and firm diaphgragm control are critical for both families of instruments.  Clarinets have a significantly greater pitch range which means you'll have to learn the adjustments in airstream & mouth/throat positioning for a lot more notes on a clarinet --- that just takes time and practice.

Answer (score 0):

I play clarinet and saxophone.  On clarinet, keeping a tight embochure and steady air stream are the two most important things.